# Is there a way to get the user locale in the valence desire2learn API?

Tags: desire2learn, valence

I making a widget for d2l platform, My widget needs to authenticate users and get their userID and locale and language information. 
I succeed in the authentication process and /d2l/api/lp/1.0/users/whoami works perfectly to get userId (UniqueName) but I cannot find any way to get user locale information.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to get the user's locale information as set in the D2L LMS. We've been recommending that third parties make use of the locale information local to the client's browser or operating system environment as the source for user locale information.